# SMS is not being sent through PLIVO from parse cloud code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, plivo

I have developed an app on parse.com

I have created following function to send SMS using plivo.

```
function sendRSVPSMS(PlivoNumber, GuestNumber, Message) {
    var payLoad = {
        src: PlivoNumber,
        dst: GuestNumber,
        text: Message
    };
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: "<My Plivo URL>",
        method: "POST",
        body: payLoad,
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log('httpRequest success');
            response.success("Sent successfully");
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log('SendSMS: Request failed');
            response.error('Request failed');
        }
    });
}
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be You forgot to specify the header for  content type.

**"Content-Type": "application/json"**

So your code will be as below

```
function sendRSVPSMS(PlivoNumber, GuestNumber, Message) {
    var payLoad = {
        src: PlivoNumber,
        dst: GuestNumber,
        text: Message
    };
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: "<My Plivo URL>",
        method: "POST",
        body: payLoad,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log('httpRequest success');
            response.success("Sent successfully");
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log('SendSMS: Request failed');
            response.error('Request failed');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Pavan, Thanks for the feedback. This just worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Pavan is correct. You need to specify the `Content-Type` header as `application/json` for Parse to make a JSON string of the body:

```
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
```

You also should `console.log(httpResponse)` (aka the Plivo API response) which will tell if you are doing something wrong (sending the wrong data, not authenticating correctly) or if you do something right. Either way it will show you an `api_id` which you can use to look in your [Plivo account dashboard debug logs](https://manage.plivo.com/logs/debug/) and figure out what need to be changed. You can also go directly to the debug logs for a specific `api_id` by making a url like this: `https://manage.plivo.com/logs/debug/api/e58b26e5-3db5-11e6-a069-22000afa135b/` and replacing `e58b26e5-3db5-11e6-a069-22000afa135b` with the `api_id` returned by your `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`